# Automatically adding images to a certain page through the Media Uploader

Tags: uploads, media-library

I have a plugin that calls the Media Uploader to allow users to add images to a Page. The uploader is being displayed and taking images fine, but it is not attaching them to Page ID 65 as I wish (or showing images attached to that Page as in the Gallery).

Am I missing something, or is this just not possible in WP? Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.manage-images-button a.button-secondary').on('click', function(){

        tb_show('Manage Front Page Images', 'media-upload.php?referer=dd-options&TB_iframe=true&post_id=65', false);
        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrly, the answer to this is to simply swap two of the parameters around -

```
tb_show('Manage Front Page Images', 'media-upload.php?referer=dd-options&post_id=65&TB_iframe=true', false);
```